# Retrieve files from FTP folder using R

Tags: r, download, ftp

I have to download some files from a password protected FTP folder.

At the moment I am able to get the list of the files contained in the folder,
this is useful because I want to select only specific files.
To do that I use the following code:

```
url <- "ftp://myurl"

filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd="myuserName:myPassword", ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
destnames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r*\n")[[1]]
destnames <- destnames[1:1000]
```

This basically selects the first 1000 files in the folder.

Now that I have the file names that I want, how do I download them to a specific folder?

Comment: Loop through your list? `myData <- lapply(destnames, function(i) getURL(paste0(url, i), userpwd = userpwd))`

Comment: @zx8754 This effectively creates a list in which each element contains the content of each file. I would like to simply move the files from the ftp folder to a local folder on my machine.

Comment: Then write it out, `writeLines` ?

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial on what I think you want to achieve: https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/web-scraping-r/#access-web-data-using-r-over-ftp